# JavaScript Pre-load Is Not Working In Some Browsers

Tags: javascript, wordpress, preload

I want to pre-load some JavaScript In Wordpress site

```
<link rel="preload" href="//mysite.co.in/gplink.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="//mysite.co.in/ouoline.js" as="script">
```

These Are perfectly working in chrome(both desktop+Mobile) But not in other browsers(Firefox, uc). what i need to change ?

Comment: [It's not supported in all browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-preload), hence why it doesn't work.

Comment: [MDN | Preloading content with rel="preload" - HTML: Hypertext Markup Language -> Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score -1):

**Please put this,**

```
<link rel="preload" href="//mysite.co.in/gplink.js" as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preload" href="//mysite.co.in/ouoline.js" as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). "*Please put this*" is not a good answer.

Comment: I don't think you understand the purpose of Stack Overflow. It's not just to answer a single question for the OP. It's a knowledge base for future visitors who come along and find this post because they are having the same issue. An "answer" that doesn't explain what the original problem was and why the suggested code solves it doesn't really help anyone. And, if you feel that you somehow shouldn't have to pay attention to the site's own guidelines for how to answer a question, your answers will probably get voted down.

Comment: can i show waiting time if these 2 java script isn't fully loaded

Comment: Please load this script into the footer.And then check.Thanks @Watcher